# Creating a separate border for each comment Django Css

Tags: jquery, html, css, django

I am having trouble finding a way to create a separate border box for each comment that is made similar to below.

[image]

However when I add a new comment the border doubles similar to below

[image]

I am currently using Django/python  here is my html file

```
  <div class="comments--section ">
    {% for comment in comments %}
    <div class="comments--border">
      <p class="comments--user">{{comment.user }}</p>
      <p class="comments--date">{{comment.date_added|date:'M d, Y' }}</p>
      <p class="comments--entry">{{ comment }}</p>


      {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
      <p>
        <a href="{% url 'blogging_logs:delete_comment' comment.id %}">Delete comment</a>
      </p>
      {% else %}
        {% if comment.user == request.user %}
          <p>
            <a href="{% url 'blogging_logs:delete_comment' comment.id %}" class="comments--delete">Delete comment</a>
          </p>
          </div>
          {% else %}
          {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
    {% empty %}
      <p>no comments entered yet.</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

css file:

```
&--section {
    width: 600px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 2
  }

  &--border {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }


  &--user {
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 0;

  }

  &--date {
    font-size: .7rem;
    font-weight: 300;
  }

  &--entry {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
```

I know the reason my border is doubling however I don't know how to get around it. If I move the div class outside of the loop it creates one large box instead of individual boxes for each comment. any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Penultimate line 7 which is `<\div>` should remove to the Penultimate line 2

Comment: You should close your `</div>` before `{% endfor %}`, not after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <div class="comments--section ">
       {% for comment in comments %}
       <div class="comments--border">
            <p class="comments--user">{{comment.user }}</p>
            <p class="comments--date">{{comment.date_added|date:'M d, Y' }}</p>
            <p class="comments--entry">{{ comment }}</p>

           {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
            <p>
               <a href="{% url 'blogging_logs:delete_comment' comment.id %}">Delete comment</a>
            </p>
          {% elif comment.user == request.user %}
            <p>
               <a href="{% url 'blogging_logs:delete_comment' comment.id %}" class="comments--delete">Delete comment</a>
            </p>

            {% else %}
              <p> ** You can add any message if you wish**
              </p>
           {% endif %}

     </div>
     {% empty %}
     <div class='comments--border'>
           <p>no comments entered yet.</p>
     </div>
     {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

Here I have changed a little bit of yuor HTML. And also there is an elif tag in django. So you can use it instead of writing if in nested.

Comment: Thank you sir. was not aware of the elif